# When I multiply together values from every 2 lines in a data field some unwanted values appear for no obvious reason

Tags: livecode

So I am working IN Livecode and I import some numbers into a field e.g.
1
2
3
4
5
6

I want to multiply every two lines, e.g. 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6.

I am using this code:

```
put 1 into x
repeat with y = x to the number of lines of field "Output"
   put the text of line x of field "Output" into value1
   put the text of line x + 1 of field "Output" into value2
   put carDistance * carTimeSeconds into carSpeed // Every two lines multiply
   repeat for each item b in value3
      put value3 into valueList[b] // Just adds the speed to a list
   end repeat
   put y + 2 into x 
end repeat
```

I get this output:
2 (correct)
12 (correct)
30 (correct)
and then 20 which is incorrect and my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've swapped some variable names in your code, hard to tell, but in any event here's one way to do what you want:

```
local theTotal
put text of fld "output" into temp
repeat with N = 2 to (number of lines of temp) step 2
   add (line N of temp) * (line (N-1) of temp) to theTotal
end repeat
```

The above assumes you're trying to get the overall total.  If you want to verify the results, you can do this, which will place a list of the products in the message box:

```
put text of fld "output" into temp
repeat with N = 2 to (number of lines of temp) step 2
   put (line N of temp) * (line (N-1) of temp) & return after theProducts
end repeat
put theProducts
```

Note that when working with fields it's more efficient to put the field's contents into a variable and work with the data there, rather than repeatedly reading from the field.